# Navigate to function definition while debugging JS

Tags: javascript, javascript-debugger

I have simple Javascript code:

```
function display_json() {
    clear_screen_since_json_input_changed();  ------> source
    var json = get_json_from_root()
    $('#display_json').text(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4));
}
```

... many lines strippped

```
function clear_screen_since_json_input_changed() {   <------- target
    ...
}
```

I debug the code in the browser, and see above code in the debug-bar of the browser.

In my favorite IDE of my prefered language (Python) I can easily navigate to the function definition by ctrl+click on `clear_screen_since_json_input_changed()`.

I tried this with firefox and chrome.

It does not work to "jump" to `function clear_screen_since_json_input_changed() {....}`

With "jump" I mean to navigate in the JS code. I don't want to change the place where the JS execution has been paused.

Somehow I feel like being on the wrong track.

How to navigate in the code while debugging JavaScript?

At the moment I use the browser to debug the code. Would a Javascript-IDE help for navigating during debugging?

Comment: All of the modern browser's developer tools provide Step, Step Over, and Step Out navigation during debugging. Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I want to  "jump" to the function definition. With other words I want to navigate in the JS code. I don't want to step/step-in/step-out (this works fine).

Comment: In Chrome at least, if you are in debugger mode and paused on a line, hover your mouse over the function in question and a tooltip will open up with a link to the definition.

Comment: I don't believe most browser dev. tools will do that.

Comment: If the debugger is halted it works. I need to rest the mouse cursor for some time, and I get a hyperlink to the js source. Is there a way to get this even if I am not actively debugging (just looking at the js source code)?

Comment: I don't believe so. Remember that as good as the dev tools have become, they aren't full fledged IDEs, so there's going to be features of IDEs that aren't present in the dev tools.